Terraform metadata_startup_script for GCP runs even though file is present to prevent it from running
Been trying to trouble shoot this for two days. Not sure if it is a terraform or GCP issue. Or my code. I'm trying to create a VM and run some installs. It then creates a file in /var/run called flag.txt. If that file is present the startup script should exit and not run on reboots. I wrote a python script to write the date and time to the flag.txt file so I could test. However, everytime I reboot the time and date are updated in the flag.txt file showing that the startup script is running.
Here is my metadata_startup_script code
metadata_startup_script = <<-EOF

#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f /var/run/flag.txt ];

then

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y gcloud

echo '${local.script_content}' > /tmp/install_docker.sh

echo '${local.flag_content}' > /tmp/date_flag.py

chmod +x /tmp/install_docker.sh

chmod +x /tmp/date_flag.py

#Below command is just to show root is executing this script

#whoami >> /usr/bin/runner_id

bash /tmp/install_docker.sh

/usr/bin/python3 /tmp/date_flag.py

else

exit 0

fi

EOF

}

Here is the date_flag.py file that creates the flag.txt file
import datetime

current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
formatted_datetime = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
file_name = f"{formatted_datetime}.txt"
with open("/var/run/flag.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write("This file was created at: " + formatted_date

Any thoughts or suggestions are welcome. This is really driving me crazy.

In your tests where do you see this failing? ... is the flag.txt created as intended? ... if [ ! -f /var/run/flag.txt ]; is that working if you test locally?

the fact that the startup script runs tells me that terraform is not the problem, all terraform will do is create the VM with that metadata_startup_script so maybe is something with that code some how that IF statement is not doing what you think

Turns out that it was where the flag.txt file was being placed. From what I'm seeing it looks like /run and /var/run are not present when the startup script runs so it does not see the flag.txt file. By the time the python file ran to write the flag file the directories were there. This was driving me nuts. :-(

wow that is quite a surprise, it would have taken me hours too ... I was thinking that something external was deleting the /var/run/flag.txt on every reboot ... so the solution is simply to put it in another location

So it turns out that /var/run is symbolically linked to /run which is created at startup. I fixed this by writing the flag.txt file to /etc.

See if you can find any official documentation and paste a link to it in the answer

In the future, you can always run the following command from the instance to get logs on the script execution:
journalctl -u google-startup-scripts.service

